# (Intuition) Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> You may refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1418874/493216) question for a formal statement of Rudin's Theorem 2.34 and the proof he provides.

Let $E \subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space and $E$ is "non-closed", i.e. it could be either "open" or "neither open nor closed". Since, $E$ is non-closed there is atleast one point $p\in X$ such that $p \notin E$ and $p$ is a limit-point of $E$. With that said, consider the following intuition

> **Intuition**: Let $N_r(p)$ be an open-ball centered at $p$ and of radius-$r$. Then, portion of every neighborhood of $p$ that falls inside $E$ can be constructed as a union of infinitely many open sets, i.e.  $N_r(p)\cap E = \cup_{\alpha}\,G_{\alpha}\,\,\forall r>0$. Then from this, we can always construct an [infinite] open-cover of $E$, as $\{\,G_{\alpha}\}\cup\{E\,\backslash\,(\cup_{\alpha}\,G_{\alpha})\}$; whose union is equal to $E$. And any finite subset of this open-cover will leave-out portions of $N_r(p)\cap E$, and hence won't be an open-cover of $E$.

Is this intuition right? And is there a better way to formalize this?

Comment: I want to know if the intuition is right? And is there a way to formalize it better, to be used as an alternate proof?

Comment: I have no idea how do you prove that “A portion of every neighborhood of 
 that falls inside   can be constructed as a union of infinitely many open sets”. Being $p$ a limit point has nothing to do with that.

I would prove other situation. I would prove that the complement of the set E is open. To prove this, you could prove that $\text{dist}(x, E)$ is greater than zero for every $x \not \in E$. Hence, the open set of points such that $\text{dist}(x, E)>0$ coincides with the complement of $E$.

Comment: I think Rudin's proof is along the lines of your suggestion. And, yeah I do think it is tricky to prove the statement “A portion of ... infinitely many open sets” -- hence, the question!

Comment: @R.W.Prado - keeping aside the formal proof; does the intuition sound right?

Comment: No, because not necessarily “non-closed'' sets are “open in a neighborhood of at least a point”. I'm pretty sure that there will be a non-closed set whose interior is empty. Maybe… the rational numbers seen as subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If the interior of the set is empty, it won't have any limit points, in which case it would trivially be closed. And in your example, $\mathbb{Q}$ seen as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ -- the irrational numbers are the limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$!

Comment: “If the interior of the set is empty, it won't have any limit points”. No… the set of the rational numbers seen as subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has empty interior, since we can approach each rational number with a sequence of irrational numbers. I think you should revise the definitions.

Comment: I've just started learning real-analysis, so, I think it will take me some time to wrap my head around it. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: A point of a set is not a limit point iff it is an isolated point. On the other hand, not necessarily a set of isolated points has an empty boundary. The set $\{ 1/n \in \mathbb{R} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ has $0$ as a boundary point, and it is a set of isolated points. You must be confused with something related to the definition of limit point. The closure of $S$ is the union of the set $S$ with its boundary. Hence, in order for a set to be closed, you can prove that its boundary is contained in $S$. I, particularly, prefer to prove that the complement of the set is open.

Comment: Why don't you try the closure of the compact subset is itself so it is closed？This technique is used more often in proving something is closed than to show its complement is open in my opinion.

Comment: In terms of rudin proof, the only intuition needed is the finite subcover. You fix a point q in the complement then for a point p in the set, you can draw two open balls of radius less than 0.5 d(p,q) center each of them thus they are not intercepted. Then you draw the same thing for every point in the set with respect to q. Since you need only finite of the balls centered at p's to cover the set, so you can take the finite interception of their corresponding open balls at q, which is open and in the complement.

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak - sounds like a good idea. I'll see if I can prove it using this route.

Comment: Let ∉. For ∈, the balls (,(,)/2) and (,(,)/2) are disjoint. The union of all these balls (,(,)/2) is a cover for . Since  is compact, it this admits a subcover. Let 1,2,⋯, be the center of the balls that "subcovers" . We have that the intersection of all the balls with center $x$ and radius (,1)/2,(,2)/2,⋯,(,)/2 does not intersect  $-$ otherwise there would be a point in , thus, in some (ℓ,(,ℓ)/2), intersecting (,(,ℓ)/2).

Comment: Since, for each ∉, the intersection of all the balls with center $x$ and radius (,1)/2,(,2)/2,⋯,(,)/2 is contained in the complement of , the complement is open. This proves that the complement of a compact in a metric space is open.